# Array is null when calling `.push`

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular9

I am working on an angular app. In my component `.ts` file I have an array as follow:

```
public myArray = [];
public dataFromAPI  = [];
```

In one of my method whenever I am trying to push a element in this array, it is giving me following error:

```
   this.appService.getData.subscribe(resp => {
      if (resp != null) {
          this.dataFromAPI = resp;
          this.dataFromAPI.forEach(element => {
            this.myArray.push(element)
          })
      }

RROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'push')
```

I don't see any mistake in my code. I always define a new array like this but first time I am getting this error. How to resolve this?

Comment: Hello, can you please add code where you `push` elements to this specific array?

Comment: @Roma, could you please do a console.log of `this` inside forEach loop to check what is the value of `this` inside forEach

Answer (score 0):

the declaration should be like below

```
public myArray:any = [];
public dataFromAPI:any  = [];
```

you should directly loop the response of the api like below (please check inside there are may be more keys inside response object, access the array through key)

```
   this.appService.getData.subscribe(resp => {
      if (resp != null) {
          resp.data.forEach(element => {
            this.myArray.push(element)
          });
      this.dataFromAPI = resp;
      }
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what syntax `public myArray = [];` is. Below will work for typescript.

```
const myArray: string[] = [];
myArray.push('string');

const myArray: number[] = [];
myArray.push(123);

const myArray: Record<string, unknown>[] = [];
myArray.push({key: 'value'});
```

Comment: what if I want to push entire javascript object as an element in array?

Comment: it's a property inside a class

Comment: @Roma updated answer for your question. and maybe you wanna `myArray = []` inside the contructor if this is a class.